# Problema para conseguir as informações solicitadas

Tags: python, back-end

Belezinha, galera.

É o seguinte, estou iniciando na programação e já me perdi em um exercício complicado rsrs.
Uma lista foi fornecida com várias informações e foi solicitado que algumas informações fossem extraídas dessas lista. A base do exercícios são as funções "if, else, elif, try, except, finally, for, in, range, break e continue".
A questão é que eu não consigo extrair essas informações, qualquer comando que eu uso, retorna um erro diferente. Na verdade estou com dificuldade para estruturas algo que me dê as informações que eu preciso.

Esse é a lista:

```
propaganda_online = [
  {'tempo_gasto_site': 68.95, 'idade': 35, 'renda_area': 61833.90, 'tempo_gasto_internet': 256.09, 'cidade': 'Wrightburgh', 'pais': 'Tunisia', 'clicou_no_ad': 0},
  {'tempo_gasto_site': 80.23, 'idade': 31, 'renda_area': 68441.85, 'tempo_gasto_internet': 193.77, 'cidade': 'West Jodi', 'pais': 'Nauru', 'clicou_no_ad': 0},
  {'tempo_gasto_site': 69.47, 'idade': 26, 'renda_area': 59785.94, 'tempo_gasto_internet': 236.50, 'cidade': 'Davidton', 'pais': 'San Marino', 'clicou_no_ad': 0},
  {'tempo_gasto_site': 68.37, 'idade': 35, 'renda_area': 73889.99, 'tempo_gasto_internet': 225.58, 'cidade': 'South Manuel', 'pais': 'Iceland', 'clicou_no_ad': 0},
  {'tempo_gasto_site': 88.91, 'idade': 33, 'renda_area': 53852.85, 'tempo_gasto_internet': 208.36, 'cidade': 'Brandonstad', 'pais': 'Myanmar', 'clicou_no_ad': 0},
  {'tempo_gasto_site': None, 'idade': 48, 'renda_area': 24593.33, 'tempo_gasto_internet': 131.76, 'cidade': 'Port Jefferybury', 'pais': 'Australia', 'clicou_no_ad': 1},
  {'tempo_gasto_site': 74.53, 'idade': 30, 'renda_area': 68862.00, 'tempo_gasto_internet': 221.51, 'cidade': 'West Colin', 'pais': 'Grenada'},
  {'tempo_gasto_site': 69.88, 'idade': 20, 'renda_area': 55642.32, 'tempo_gasto_internet': 183.82, 'cidade': 'Ramirezton', 'pais': 'Ghana', 'clicou_no_ad': 0}
```

Foi solicitado extrair as seguintes informações e utilizando a estrutura abaixo de cada um:

1.1. Crie uma lista chamada paises com o pais dos usuários com mais de 30 anos.

```
   paises = []
   for dado_de_usuario in propaganda_online:
   ...
   print(paises)
```

1.2. Crie uma lista chamada leads com a renda dos usuários que clicaram na propaganda.

```
   leads = []
   for dado_de_usuario in propaganda_online:
   ...

   print(leads)
```

1.3. Crie uma lista chamada cidades com a cidade dos usuários que passaram mais de 70 segundos no site.

```
   cidades = []

  for dado_de_usuario in propaganda_online:
  ...

  print(cidades)
```

Eu não quero inserir as informações manualmente, acredito que não faz sentido, mas não consigo encontrar um "norte" sobre qual estrutura de código seguir para chegar ao resultado solicitado. Comecei meu curso a menos de 2 semanas, agradeceria muito se alguém pudesse me dar uma direção sobre como começar a extrair as informações dentro dessa estrutura de código, utilizando o "propaganda_online".

Desde já eu agradeço.

PS: Estou usando o Google Colab e o curso é Back-end Python

Answer (score 0):

Como seu intuito é aprender a utilizar a lógica de python, não vou responder as perguntas específicas que você fez.

Mas a lista que você tem é uma lista de dicionários. Dicionários são uma estrutura built in do python que associa valores à chaves do modo  `{"chave":"valor"}`. Se quiser saber mais sobre métodos desse tipo de estrutura de dado, acessa [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Basicamente o que você vai precisar saber para resolver os seus problemas é:

- Quando você itera sobre uma lista em cada iteração você esta acessando diretamente o objeto armazenado na lista (no seu caso dicionários);
- Para acessar um valor de um dicionário basta passar o valor da chave correspondente, ex:

```
>>> random_dict = {"chave":"valor"}
>>> variavel = random_dict["chave"]
>>> variavel
"valor"
```

- Por fim, para adicionar elementos à uma lista, você pode usar o método `append`. Nele você passa como argumento o que deseja adicionar à lista e ele vai ser colocado na última posição. Caso queira ver mais métodos de listas, pode ler [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Answer (score -3):

Ola. Minha primeira postagem no grupo. Faz varios dias que vc postou a duvida, nao sei se ja resolveu. Vou responder de forma simples a primeira pergunta. Acredito que te dara um norte !!

```
paises = []
for dado in propaganda_online:
    if dado['idade']>= 30:
        paises.append(dado['pais'])
    
print(paises)
```